# Uploading files higher than few MBs directly to S3 using Multer-S3 using express

Tags: amazon-s3, multer, multer-s3

I'm trying to upload PDF files using Multer-S3 directly to S3 using express server.
For some reason, it works when I try to upload SVG file it works great, but when I'm trying to upload something else like PDF there is no error, but when I try to access to file in my S3 bucket it's not opening or showing a blank PDF page.

My code:
filesService.js

```
const multer = require('multer');
const multerS3 = require('multer-s3-transform');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const BUCKET_NAME = process.env.FILES_BUCKET_NAME;
const s3 = new AWS.S3({});

var limits = {
   files: 1, // allow only 1 file per request
   fileSize: 20 * 1024 * 1024 *1024, // (replace MBs allowed with your desires)
};

const upload = multer({
   limits: limits,
   storage: multerS3({
      acl: "public-read",
      s3: s3,
      bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
      contentType: multerS3.AUTO_CONTENT_TYPE,
      key: (req, file, cb) => {
          console.log(file);
          cb(null, file.originalname)
      }
  })
}).single('file');

module.exports = {upload};
```

route.js

```
router.post('/files', async (req, res ,next) => {
await filesService.upload(req, res, (err) => {
   if(err) {
       console.error(err);
   } else {
       console.log(req.file);
       location = req.file.location;
       res.status(200).send({link: req.file.location});
   }
});

res.status(500);
})
```

I'm trying to do it using Postman with the following configurations:
Headers: Content-Type - multipart/form-data
Body: key: file, value: PDF selected

There's no error returned from my route, but again, when I try to access a file different than SVG it doesnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative, and since we chose to make our PDF much bigger, we took a decision to move the PDF generator from the front-end to the backend, so there was no need using Multer for that anymore, we generated the PDF on Express backend server using `pdfkit` npm package, then uploaded it once it done generating the PDF directly from the same server to the related S3 bucket, using `aws-sdk` npm package.

So, finally what we chose to do is just to send the related PDF data from the front to the backend and generate the PDF there.